# What is the type of function inside a class by default if no args are passed?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

```py
class A:
    @classmethod
    def a(x):
        print('a')

    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print('b')

    def c():
        print('c')

    def d(self): #instance method
        print(self)

A.a() # calling using class

A.b() # calling using class
A().b() # calling using instance

A.c() # calling using class

A().d() # calling using the object

A().c() # calling using instance but returning error
```

I've created a simple class and different methods, what is the type of method c( ) here? it is not static as if it was static method it could have been called by an instance too but it returns an error in that case, it is not an class method either as if it was, we should have get argument like cls while defining the function, so what type is the method c( ) here?

Comment: In my opinion, @staticmethod decorator is more for readability rather than functionality. The method should work as intended with or without the decorator. However, the best practice is for sure to add the decorator.

Comment: No brother, decorator isnt only for readability, it also kind of specifying the method type so the function works as specified, I experimented few cases and can confirm this.Thank you for your opinion btw, have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@staticmethod` in *Python 3* if you want to call the method on an instance too. If you don't use the decorator, the method will always be passed the instance as the first parameter, causing a TypeError.

Here is an example:

```
>>> class A:
>>>     def f():
>>>         print('hello')

>>> A.f()
hello
>>> A().f()
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

```
>>> class A:
>>>     @staticmethod
>>>     def f():
>>>         print('hello')

>>> A.f()
hello
>>> A().f()
hello
```

In *Python 3* there is no difference between a function defined inside a class or a function defined outside a class. Both of them are normal functions.

The `self` parameter (or maybe `cls`) comes into picture only when you access the function through an instance. Hence you don't get any error if you don't use an instance.

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time to answer my question, btw could you explain whats the difference between A.f( ) and A( ).f( ) isn't A() the constructor? much appreciated :D

Comment: Yes, it's the constructor. My example simply wants to show you that with the first method *you can't* call the function using an instance (i.e., an object created with the constructor). I.e., you can't do this `a = A(); a.f()`. You can only call the function by using the class name, i.e. by using `A.f()`. Instead, if you use `@statimethod` you can use both methods. Please upvote and mark my answer as accepted if you think it is useful

Comment: Sure, so can I conclude that python declares the type of function like static/classmethods dynamically on how the method is being called, just like declaration of variables in on runtime?

Comment: So if we call a method just using class without passing any args its static method by default, if we use a decorator @classmethod and take an arg in the method definition it is class method and calling the method using an object is instance method?